# Removing data from a json file on bases of their value

Tags: json, python-2.7, dictionary

I had produced a script to parse some blast files from different samples. As I wanted to know the genes that all the samples had it commum I created a list, and a dictionary to count them. I have also produced a json file from the dictionary. Now I want to removed those genes whose counts are less than 100, as this is the number of samples, either from the dictionary or from the json file but I don't know how to. 
This is part of the code:

```
 ###to produce a dictionary with the genes, and their repetitions
for extracted_gene in matches:
    if extracted_gene in matches_counts:
        matches_counts[extracted_gene]+=1
    else:
        matches_counts[extracted_gene]=1
print matches_counts #check point
#if matches_counts[extracted_gene]==100:
    #print extracted_gene
#to convert a dictionary into a txt file and format it with json

with open('my_gene_extraction_trial.txt', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(matches_counts,file, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',',':'))

print 'Parsing has finished'
```

I had tried different ways to do so:
a) ignoring the else statement but then it will give me an empty dict
b)trying to print only the ones whose values is 100, but it does not get printed
c) I read the documentation about json but I only can see how to delete elements by objects but not by values.
Can I anyone help me with this issue, please? This is getting me mad!

Comment: Not sure I understand your issue but... if `x` is a dictionary of genes and `y` is a dictionary of match counts: `for gene in x: if y[gene] < 100: del x[gene]`. This will remove the "gene" entry from x. You can create a copy of x so you aren't deleting them from the original dictionary if you need to. You will be left with x as a dictionary of genes with 100 or more matches.

Comment: No, I have a list, "matches", to store the genes, and a dictionary, "matches_counts", to store the genes and their counts. And I would like to removed the 'extra genes' from the dictionary.

Comment: Make a copy of  the dictionary `matches_counts`, let's call it `copy`; `for gene in matches_counts: if matches_counts[gene] < 100: del copy[gene]`. Now copy is a dictionary of genes: matches, where matches > 100. You can iterate through the gene names with `copy.keys()`.

Comment: @illiteratecoder- I had added the following code to the script:`for extracted_gene in matches_counts: if matches_counts[extracted_gene]<2: del counts_100[extracted_gene] print counts_100` But it gives me the error **RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration**

Comment: @illiteratecoder- this is the way I copied it by `import copy`, and then adding the new dict to the script `matches=[]
matches_counts={} 
counts_100=copy.deepcopy(matches_counts)`

Comment: did you do `counts_100 = matches_counts.copy()` ?

Comment: There must be something in your code not shown. Using copy.deepcopy to create the copy, if I iterate through matches_counts and del from the copy I get no error. Where did you insert this code? It should be before the `with open...` line.

Comment: @illiteratecoder- I changed it, and now the error is this **KeyError: u"gene_1299 ['replicative DNA helicase']"**. And I know that there is only 1 copy of that gene

Comment: Can you confirm that "gene_1299 ['replicative DNA helicase']" is indeed a key in both matches_counts and counts_100?

Comment: @illiteratecoder-                                                                                  
  `for extracted_gene in matches:
 if extracted_gene in matches_counts:
  matches_counts[extracted_gene]+=1
 else:
  matches_counts[extracted_gene]=1
print matches_counts #check point
for extracted_gene in matches_counts:
 if matches_counts[extracted_gene]<2:
  del counts_100[extracted_gene]
  print counts_100` . That's the way I did it. I had 2 because I am trying with just to folder, just for speed purposes.

Comment: Where do you create the copy? It should be between those two `for ... in ...` loops (after that `# check point` line).

Comment: @illiteratecoder-Thanks a lot! I finally got it. I would like to mark the question as answer but someone marked me down the other day, and I lost that privilege.

Comment: Don't worry about it! I'm glad we could work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what it should look like:

```
# matches (list) and matches_counts (dict) already defined
for extracted_gene in matches:
    if extracted_gene in matches_counts:
        matches_counts[extracted_gene] += 1 
    else: matches_counts[extracted_gene] = 1

print matches_counts #check point

# Create a copy of the dict of matches to remove items from
counts_100 = matches_counts.copy()

for extracted_gene in matches_counts:
    if matches_counts[extracted_gene] < 100: 
        del counts_100[extracted_gene] 

print counts_100
```

Let me know if you still get errors.